# Number of nodes and whitespace in the DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to count the number of nodes within a section and I got this:

```
function whatChildren(e) 
{
    var Cnodes= e.target.childNodes;

    document.write(e.target.nodeName + " number of nodes " + Cnodes.length);
}
```

But when I try to get the number of nodes:

If I got this:

```
<section>
      <h2>Text</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
</section>
```

I get a length of 5 nodes. When I actually got 4 nodes.

But if I put it in this way:

```
<section><h2>Text</h2><p>Text</p></section>
```

I get a length of 2 nodes... And it is the same thing from above...

I don't know what is the problem... I think it's something related with white spaces but I don't know how to deleted to get the correct number of nodes with this.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

childNodes includes all nodes, that means TextNodes are included. Here you have two elements and three textnodes

```
<section><TextNode>\n</TextNode>
      <h2>Text</h2><TextNode>\n</TextNode>
      <p>Text</p><TextNode>\n</TextNode>
</section>
```

With the minified version you just have two elements.

```
<section><h2>Text</h2><p>Text</p></section>
```

Since you said you have 4 nodes I presume you meant `h2`, Text, `p`, Text, if you want your function to be recursive, you should make it recursive.

```
function whatChildren(e) {
    var nodes= [].slice.call(this.childNodes),
        len = nodes.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i],
            childNodes = node.childNodes || [],
            nodesLength = childNodes.length;

        nodes = nodes.concat(childNodes);
        len += nodesLength;
    }

    console.log(this.nodeName + " number of nodes " + len);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ojebuv/2/edit#source)

Comment: ... except in IE < 9, which ignores (most) whitespace text nodes

Comment: @TimDown I forgot IE sucks :(

Answer (score 0):

You can count the correct child numbers with following code:

```
function whatChildren(e) 
{
   var kids = e.target.childNodes.length;
   var realKids = 0;
   var parent = e.target;
   var i = 0;

   while(i < kids){
      if(parent.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3){
         realKids++;
      }
      i++;
   }

   document.write(e.target.nodeName + " number of nodes " + realKids);
}
```

Take a look at this article for more detail:

- http://blog.tegneblokken.net/2009/08/counting-childnodes-with-javascript-the-whitespace-incident/

I hope this helps :-)